# How to specify whether EffectiveIdentity is required in PowerBI

Tags: dataset, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I'm embedding a Power BI report in a web page, using the [AppOwnsData sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/App%20Owns%20Data) as a base.  Everything is working fine, using the Service Principal for authentication.  However, now I'd like to pass through an ["Effective Identity"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-row-level-security).  When I initially try this, I get the error:

> InvalidRequest: Creating embed token for accessing dataset xxx
>   shouldn't have effective identity

When I'm generating the token request parameters, if I query the dataset (like this):

```
var dataset = await client.Datasets.GetDatasetByIdInGroupAsync(workspaceId, datasetId);
isEffectiveIdentityRequired = dataset.IsEffectiveIdentityRequired;
```

I get a false - i.e. Effective Identity is **not** required.

I, therefore, have a two part question:

- Is it possible to change this from the dataset configuration in PowerBI (or if not, how can this ever be true)?
- Am I correct in assuming that `dataset.IsEffectiveIdentityRequired == false` would cause this error if the effective identity were passed through (the wording implies that whilst it may not be *required*, it *may* still be provided).

Comment: About the first part of your question, `IsEffectiveIdentityRequired` is not something that can be changed directly. It depends on the datasource. If it is `true` and you don't provide effective identity, you should get an error. Unfortunately I don't have an answer on the second part of your question.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov You say that it "depends on the datasource".  In what way, exactly, does it depend?  What properties of the data source would make this true?

Comment: e.g. Live connection to Analysis Services will set this, I believe. If Power BI must pass the identity of the current user to the database (so maybe the storage mode is not `Imported`), then the flag will be set.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have configured dataset roles using Power BI desktop application, you can learn how to set these roles [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-row-level-security#adding-roles-with-power-bi-desktop). Using effectiveIdentity will work only after the roles are set for the dataset